# Elasticsearch and MongoDB IndexMissingException 404 Error

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4, elasticsearch, redis

I use this command for to delete old index in Elastic Search.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear'
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_ALL/'
```

and i use this command on SSH

Elastic Search:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_flush'
curl http://localhost:9200/_mapping
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_ALL
```

Laravel:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
```

and MongoDB

```
sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

i want only delete my old cache and index files. and finally i restart my linux centos server:

```
shutdown -r now
```

I have same problem now. Elasticsearch error:

```
{"error":"IndexMissingException[[shopping] missing]","status":404}
```

Does anyone have any information about the problem